# Redirecting the user to login when ASP.NET session times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wrote a filter on all my pages so that the user cannot make any transactions if their session is over. If the user's session ends while the page is changing, if I refresh the page, it redirects me to login. But if I make a post action with ajax inside the page, it does not redirect.I want the user to not be able to take action even on the page they are on if their session ends.

`web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

Auth filter:

```
public class Auth : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UsersDetails"] == null)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = urlHelper.Action("Login", "Login");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[Auth]
[Exc]
public class ProductController : Controller
```